Correcting my Latin Motto
I have a business name with the letters GPV, which relates to a motto I came up with, "We Create, We Excel, To Live", using the latin words, "Generatum, Praestatus, Victus" (or could be Vivere).  While this exists as motivation for the name, I rarely make reference to it or use it for fear of embarrassment that it is not very close to the intended meaning, or has all wrong cases/endings to the words. It is enough for it to loosely translate, but I don't want to use a motto without comment from someone who knows latin. Can someone correct or validate the latin, or offer an appropriate latin phrase that is similar to the motto intent for the GPV acronym?

I would say the first two words could be rendered as indicative verbs rather than passive participles, something like "Generamus, Praestamus." For the third word, assuming that by "To Live" you mean "in order to live," it's a little tricky. Latin doesn't generally use a stand-alone infinitive to convey purpose the way English does. Perhaps one could use an active participle with circumstantial meaning: "Generamus, Praestamus, Viventes"? You can also use more natural constructions like “ad vivendum” or “ut vivamus,” giving for example Generamus, Praestamus, ut Vivamus. But these arguably introduce an extra letter into the acronym (unless you’re fine with disregarding the extra letter the way English often does with “the” or “of”).

Thank you.  This is great!  And I think I'm starting understand these constructions better as well.   The "amus" gives us active plural versions of the words, to denote that "we are doing these things", and then we either use a looser contextual idea of "viventes", living, or the more literal "ut vivamas", "to live" or "that we may live".

I like them both and now just have to decide which to use. I'm leaning towards the latter. I would use it with english tagline next to it, perhaps on the last slide of a presentation or suchlike, so either way, people will get the intention and its now got some basis in the correct latin, which is excellent. Thank again :-)
